# dismiss keyboard in textview while scroll

Tags: ios, textview, keyboard-events

I am new to IOS i tried lot but still i am failed while scrolling when user touches any of the textview keyboard appear return not working.

screenshot for my output screen:

[image: staring page and keyboard appear page]

Answer (score 7):

You can dismiss keyboard with dismiss on drag option on Tableview .

scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```